# Is it possible to overwrite == logic of std::string for hashing?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

What I'm trying to do is create hash for anagram using prime; however it's a little bit inconvenient having to create an extra `struct key` because of the `==` operator. Is there a workaround to overload the existing `==` of std::string?

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int F[26] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,  
             31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71,
             73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101}; 

size_t f(const string &s) {
  size_t r = 1;
  for (auto c : s) {
    r *= F[c - 'a'] % 9999997;
  }
  return r;
}

// this struct seemed redundant!
struct key {
  const string s;

  key(const string s)
    :s(s) {}

  bool operator ==(const key &k) const {
    return f(s) == f(k.s);
  }
};

struct hasher {
  size_t operator()(const key &k) const {
    return f(k.s); 
  }
};

int main() {
  unordered_map<key, int, hasher> cnt;
  cnt[key{"ab"}]++;
  cnt[key{"ba"}]++;
  cout << cnt[key{"ab"}] << endl;
}
```

Comment: @RainbowTom: Don't; `std::string` isn't designed as a base class but as a value class. C++ **will** stop you from inheriting from `int` and **should** stop you from inheriting from `std::string`.

Comment: @MSalters Smarter every day, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unordered_map` is declared as

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>
> class unordered_map;
```

so you can substitute your own equality predicate as the fourth template parameter.

Comment: I've seen `<unordered_set>` in the include list and read no further. >_<

Comment: @bipll I cleaned up the includes in the question.

Answer (score -3):

Create your own class derived from **std::string** and add your overload operator to that new class

Comment: This is dangerous ; the base class does not have virtual functions, so if you then passed it to any interface that accepts `std::string`, the wrong equality would be used